# setting up egit repos for team programming

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to find out what would be the best way to set up egit repos for mutliple developers.

I found some arguments to set up independant repos for each developer and then the recommendation to merge the files by setting the respective external upstream repo to eg developer B in Eclipse of developer A so A can pull and merge with B. However A then needs to change the repo back to his own all the time. And switching upstream repos in the settings is quite cumbersome.

Alternatively all developers could work off the same repo  in different braches - then merging would be easier since noone has to go to settings and change the upstream repo. On the other side this is also kind of "dangerous" since every developer is working on the same repo without restrictions (so I heard)

Which way is better in the long run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the long run, having *one* upstream repository is easier to manage.

Each developer can make their own branches locally.
They should agree on a common branch to push to though. It can be master, or a feature branch (if a few of them are collaborating to a specific feature).

The idea is, before each push, to `pull --rebase` that branch from the upstream repo in order to replay your local work (the commits you haven't pushed already) on top of upstream/branch (`git pull --rebase` will fetch and then rebase your local work on top of what has just been fetch).
That way, a developer will only push commits which will be merged on upstream as a fast-forward merge.

In EGit terms, that `pull --rebase` is configured when you [create a tracking branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branch_Creation_Dialog).

[image: pull rebase]

> Rebase: When pulling, new changes will be fetched from upstream and the remote tracking branch will be updated. Then the current local branch will be rebased onto the updated remote tracking branch

Comment: Thanks - we have just switched today to your recommended structure too. I agree, it's easier than separate repos. Just needed a confirmation from a PRO. Thanks very much :-)